# How to print output for both a failure to load the page as expected and the page loading as expected

Tags: node.js, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

If the `browser.wait` command times out, I still want to print out the contents of the page.
I also still want it to fail the test in the case of a timeout.

I'm using selenium chromedriver.

#### What I have, so far:

```
    it('Test# 3', function() {
        var i = 3;

        util.browserGet(url, domainName, token);
        browser.wait(ec.presenceOf(element(by.className("pagination-bottom"))), 20000, 'Took Too Long').then(function() {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
                writePngFile(png, 'test_' + (i) + '_screenshot.png');
            })
        });
    });
```

#### What I'd like to do is have an else/onError/finally so I always print the screenshot:

```
    it('Test# 3', function() {
        var i = 3;

        util.browserGet(url, domainName, token);
        browser.wait(ec.presenceOf(element(by.className("pagination-bottom"))), 20000, 'Took Too Long')
        .then(function() {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
                writePngFile(png, 'test_' + (i) + '_screenshot.png');
            })
        })
        .else(function() {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
                writePngFile(png, 'test_' + (i) + '_screenshot.png');
            })
        });
    });

    it('Test# 3', function() {
        var i = 3;

        util.browserGet(url, domainName, token);
        browser.wait(ec.presenceOf(element(by.className("pagination-bottom"))), 20000, 'Took Too Long')
        .finally(function() {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
                writePngFile(png, 'test_' + (i) + '_screenshot.png');
            })
        });
    });
```

Tool Versions:

```
    "loglevel": "^1.6.6",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "puppeteer": "^1.19.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer my question, but if I use `browser.sleep(5000)` instead of the `browser.wait` command, I can print out the information.

However, now you loose the validation.

I will not be marking this as the answer, but thought I should mention it in case it helps someone else.

```
    it('Test# 3', function() {
        var i = 3;

        util.browserGet(url, domainName, token);
        browser.sleep(5000).then(function() {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
                writePngFile(png, 'test_' + (i) + '_screenshot.png');
            })
        });
    });
```